# Method not found:DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

While running project on .netStandart2.0 get an exception
Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection, System.Action`1, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLifetime)'.'

Could someone help me please with this?

Comment: Does your project reference the nuget package "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore"?

Comment: yes, version 1.1.2

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore to version 2.0.1.
Version 1.1.2 doesn't support .NET Standard 2.0, it requires 1.3 of .NET Standard

[image]

Comment: But the case is that i try to add db context from DAL project which based on .net framework 4.6 is it possible to integrate somehow them?

Comment: Update the DAL project to .NET Framework 4.7.1, it has full .NET Standard 2.0 support. https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/514

Comment: But why in WEB project which also have entityframeworkcore.1.1.2 it works but in azure functions project with the same ef core version it doesn't work?

Comment: Bc one project is using .NET Framework 4.6.1 and one is using .NET Standard 2.0. From what I  can tell. Just update the project, is no buggy, not much breaking changes for both.

Answer (score 0):

I updated all packages, projects and everything in my project and it is fixed now.
Some of them had dependencies on each other, So I went to

- NuGet package manager
- Update tab
- Check all dependencies
- Update all

This worked for me.